# Jmeter - What is the best extractor to use on a json message?

Tags: json, jmeter, text-extraction

Currently testing system where the output is in the form of formatted json.

As part of my tests I need to extract and validate two values from the json record.

The values both have individual identifiers on them but don't appear in the same part of the record, so I can't just grab a single long string.

Loose format of the information in both cases:

```
"identifier1": [{"identifier2":"idname","values":["bit_I_want!]}]
```

In the case of the bit I want, this can either be a single quoted value (e.g. "12345") or multiple quoted values (e.g. "12345","23456","98765").

In both cases I'm only interested in validating the whole string of values, not individual values from the set.

Can anyone recommend which of the various extractors in Jmeter would be best to achieve this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious choicse seems to be [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)), it allows not only executing arbitrary JSON queries but conditionally failing the sampler basing on actual and expected result match.

The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JSON Plugins JMeter Plugins Manager]

Comment: I was attempting to use this and having done some more research, it turns out that the reason it wasn't working was that I was lacking a number of the files required in the \ext directory. Unfortunately can't use the Plugins manager due to some system issues at my work, so having to download the individual files from Maven Central. :(

Answer (score 0):

JMeter 3.1 comes with [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to parse JSON response. you could use this expression `$.identifier1[0].values` 
as the JSON Path to extract the `values`.

If your JSON response is going to simple always as shown in your question, you could use Regular Expression Extractor as well. Advantage is it is faster than JSON extractor. The regular expression would be `"values":\[(.*?)\]`

Reference: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-response-data-extractors-comparison/